BigQuery: how to check query frequency for all tables in dataset
In BigQuery, I have a dataset that contains 379 tables. Most of them are accessed (i.e. queried) quite often, but quite a few were created just for testing purposes and are no longer accessed. I am planning to exclude those.
My question is: for each table in that dataset, how can I count how many times the table has been queried in the last, say, 365 days?
I am not sure if BigQuery has this capability, since I use it from within R and Python.

have you checked this post? https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Retrieving-Last-Access-Date-for-BigQuery-Tables-Based-on/m-p/646819
